# How to build query to select rows with List of possible value Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have entity

```
User {
    long id;
    String firstname;
}
```

And I would like to have query with many firstname like:

```
select * from user where firstname in names;
```

Where names are:
List names = new ArrayList();
names.add("Kowalsky");
names.add("Smith");

How this can be done using spring jpa data meta language?
I've tried already:

```
List<User> findByFirstName(List<String> firstName);
```

but id doesnt work.

please help

Comment: try findByFirstNameIn(List<String> firstName). You can also try findAllByFirstNameIn(List<String> firstName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
List<User> findByFirstNameIn(List<String> firstName);
```

You need to use `In` keyword when you are passing a List